# How not to show the welcome message of emacs/win32

Tags: windows-7, emacs, emacsw32

Whenever I use emacs/w32, I get the following message.

What's annoying is that I click the 'Never show it again', all the times, but it doesn't work.

[image]

Is there any way not to show the welcome message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `.emacs` file, add the following line:

```
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)
```

where this file is located in Windows depends on several things. I recommend you look into this answer/question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189490/where-can-i-find-my-emacs-file-for-emacs-running-on-windows/189509#189509